# Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck with this error. please help..

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Request header field x-access-token is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: What is unclear about it? Either don't send the `x-access-token` header or change the server side code / configuration to allow it.

Comment: You should enable CORS in your backend. Look [this](http://enable-cors.org) for the code

Comment: getting proper response by using postman. but not working on client side

Comment: @gianlucatursi how to enable CORS on client side

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas it's only server side. You run your angularjs app in a webserver? try to open index.html with double click

Answer (score 3):

Your server should return that it accepts custom headers (like x-access-token). For example, if you are using nodejs with expressjs, try this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // keep this if your api accepts cross-origin requests
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Access-Token");
   next();
});
```

If your server is in PHP, you need to do the same:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // keep this if your api accepts cross-origin requests
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Access-Token");
```

Ps: Access-Control-Allow-Headers doesn´t accept wildcards '*' as value.